# Titanium label - Interprete unicode from server

Tags: unicode, titanium, appcelerator

I would like to display icons from a font in my app. All is ok if I compile files with the unicode in the text value of the label.

My goal is to change the icon displayed according to the API response. Is it possible to interprete the unicode from the text returned by the API ?

Here's an example :

```
var picto = Ti.UI.createLabel({ // WORKS
    text:'\uf019',
    color:'black',
    font:{
        fontFamily:'icons',
        fontSize:40
    }
});

Ti.API.Info(apiResponse.icon); // \uf019 
var picto = Ti.UI.createLabel({ // DON'T WORK
    text:apiResponse.icon,
    color:'black',
    font:{
        fontFamily:'icons',
        fontSize:40
    }
});
```

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Please provide an example. It is no problem to use a label with an icon font and set the text to "\uf19c" and it will display the icon (e.g. the bank symbol from FontAwesome).

Comment: @miga I've updated my message :)

Comment: that looks correct. Perhaps try a replace("\\","\”) or so. It might be escaped

Comment: @Clément it might be due to that JSON.parse does something wrong in apiResponse.icon. You can try this `text: '\u' + apiResponse.icon`

Comment: @PrashantSaini I can't do that, there is an error during compilation :
Failed to parse ***/index.js
[ERROR] :  SyntaxError: Invalid hex-character pattern in string [line 356, column 51]
[ERROR] : var logo = Ti.UI.createLabel({ text:'\u'+apiResp.icon, color:'black', top:0, touchEnabled:false, font:{fontFamily:'icons', fontSize:40 } });

Comment: @miga I tried to do : text : apiResponse.icon.replace("\\", "\") ... but the end of the line becomes green (as if I forgot a " or a ' ) :/

Comment: @Clément, I have added an answer and see if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comments, you just need to escape the unicode text like this:

**Case 1: apiResponse.icon should be = f019**

```
var picto = Ti.UI.createLabel({ // DON'T WORK
    text : "\\u" + apiResponse.icon,    \\ I have escaped 'u' character, so it should work now
    color:'black',
    font:{
        fontFamily:'icons',
        fontSize:40
    }
});
```

If case 1 doesn't work, then you may try this:

**Case 2: apiResponse.icon = 0xf019**

```
var picto = Ti.UI.createLabel({ // DON'T WORK
    text : String.fromCharCode(apiResponse.icon),    // it will make sure to convert unicode into a character
    color:'black',
    font:{
        fontFamily:'icons',
        fontSize:40
    }
});
```

Comment: It works with the 2nd method! Thanls a lot @Prashant :)

Comment: @Clément Please mark this answer as accepted to help find right answers for other users with similar issues.

Comment: @PrashantSaini How to show `\uF0298` ? For me 4 char unicode works but more than 4 char doesn't work e.g. this code only prints 8 (the last character) and ignores the first 4 characters.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the way , you are using unicode not SB unicode.
SBunicodes are 4 digit codes which you used , 
there is example of question. in xml and JS.

example 1st xml:

`<Label id="actionDl"  top="250">\ue012</Label>`

example 2nd js:

```
    a="\uE105"; \\ code from response ;
var incode=Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text : a,
    top : 300, 

});
```

check unicodes and SBunicode on flowing link for better for same .
http://punchdrunker.github.io/iOSEmoji/table_html/
I think its helpfull
[image: example attached]

Comment: I think I had tried it before and it doesn't work, but maybe there was another problem. It works with the method above. But thanks for your answer :)